# QT Open default file explorer on *nix

Tags: qt, qt4, directory, qprocess

I have the following:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QApplication::applicationPath);
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)

process->start("explorer.exe",  QStringList() << path);

#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)

process->start("open", QStringList() << path);

#endif
```

How I can achieve the same behavior for let say Ubuntu?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [QDesktopServices](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) and its openUrl function:

```
QString path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
```

It should work with all OS'es. I have tested it only in Windows.

Comment: Works like charm on Windows XP SP2, Mac OSX 10.6.4, and Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm... for me (on Windows), this is actually opening the file using the default file association. For instance, it's opening a .wav file in Media Player rather than navigating to it in Windows Explorer. Any idea how to get the Explorer-like behaviour?

Comment: I guess that you have to pass the directory containing the file as argument instead of the file itself.